# Local Sip profile and peer profile have the same domain, yet the call can still be made

Tags: android, sip, voip, twilio

I'd just starting to get my feet wet with Sip, playing around with the SipDemo included as an SDK sample.

My app would only make outgoing calls to [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sip/sending-sip-how-it-works), and ideally there would be no "Sip Provider", my app just connects straight to Twilio. I wasn't sure if this would work, but it does and I am able to complete the call and talk to myself.

Register to my sip domain created on Twillio with the required credentials for access:

```
    public void onRegister(View view)
    {
        String username = "myusername";
        String domain = "mytestsip.sip.twilio.com";
        String password = "mypassword";

        SipProfile.Builder builder = null;
        try {
           builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
            builder.setPassword(password);
            me = builder.build();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            manager.open(me);
        } catch (SipException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Initiate the call, using the Twilio Sip domain and bogus credentials:

```
    public void initiateCall() {
        try {
            SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                    call.startAudio();
                    call.setSpeakerMode(true);
                    call.toggleMute();
                    //updateStatus(call);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                    //updateStatus("Ready.");
                }
            };
            SipProfile.Builder builder2 = new SipProfile.Builder("blah", "mytestsip.sip.twilio.com");
            builder2.setPassword("mehpass");
            SipProfile other = builder2.build();
            call = manager.makeAudioCall(me, other, listener, 30);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
           ...
        }     
    }
```

How does this work? Every example of a Sip client mentions needing a Sip Provider for the local profile. How am I able to use the same domain for the local and peer profiles? My goal is to learn how Sip works, so I am looking for a detailed high level explanation of what is happening here.

Note, I'm using a Sip client and not the Android Twilio SDK for a reason, so you don't need to mention that it's available.

Comment: can you show us the protocol messages?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Do you want to implement your own sip provider ? or you wanna use it as a P2P service ?

Comment: My app calls Twilio, which runs a script. The script calls a regular phone number. What I am wondering about is the setup in the code above. I don't understand the mechanics of making a call from 'myself' (localProfile) to the same domain as myself. The reason I am asking is because I have to figure out how to work a sip client in native code, since the client included with Android doesn't fully meet my need. So I want to understand as much as possible.